# Changing Array of elements to multiple array of elements

Tags: python

How do I split seperated elements in an array to new elements with separated elements within them.

The idea is to change this

```
[ "Tiger Nixon, System Architect, Edinburgh, 5421, 2011/04/25", "Garrett Winters, Accountant, Tokyo, 422, 2011/07/25" ]
```

to this

```
[
  [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25" ],
  [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25"]
]
```

I tried this code but it didnt work. I set my_string to the top array.

```
my_list = my_string.split(",")
```

Comment: Would love to see what you've tried, and why it didn't work?

Comment: please see above

Comment: what's the criteria to separate these?

Comment: Yeah i am trying to figure out how to separate that array of two elements which has commas in it above to a array that split them into new arrays and within those has an array of elements seperated by the commas.

Comment: maybe i am not understanding

Comment: @johnsamcock Check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54002142/3091398). I hope it helps.

Comment: wow ok i understand now we can just split based on commas since it has it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
# initial list
mystring = [ "Tiger Nixon, System Architect, Edinburgh, 5421, 2011/04/25", "Garrett Winters, Accountant, Tokyo, 422, 2011/07/25" ]
# empty list to store new values 
array = []
# loop through the list and split each value 
for i in mystring:
  array.append(i.split(",")) # splits into list and appends it a new list 
print(array) # prints the resultant array
```

You can also use the below one liner list comprehension method.

```
mystring = [string.split(",") for string in mystring]
```

*Output*:

```
[['Tiger Nixon', ' System Architect', ' Edinburgh', ' 5421', ' 2011/04/25'], ['Garrett Winters', ' Accountant', ' Tokyo', ' 422', ' 2011/07/25']]
```

See the code in action [here](https://repl.it/repls/EmbarrassedDramaticLocus).

Answer (score 4):

```
[i.split(',') for i in list_of_words]
```

output:

```
[['Tiger Nixon', ' System Architect', ' Edinburgh', ' 5421', ' 2011/04/25'], ['Garrett Winters', ' Accountant', ' Tokyo', ' 422', ' 2011/07/25']]
```

I think it helps!

Comment: wow ok i understand now we are just splitting based on comma and we can use pythons code

Answer (score 2):

Use `list comprehension` with `split()`

```
l = [ "Tiger Nixon, System Architect, Edinburgh, 5421, 2011/04/25", "Garrett Winters, Accountant, Tokyo, 422, 2011/07/25" ]

print([i.split(",") for i in l])
```

Output:

```
[['Tiger Nixon', ' System Architect', ' Edinburgh', ' 5421', ' 2011/04/25'],
 ['Garrett Winters', ' Accountant', ' Tokyo', ' 422', ' 2011/07/25']]
```